# Getting anchor tag text to truncate inside an html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to truncate anchor tag text in a  element.  I've added `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` to the style on my anchor tag, but it still wraps.  Here's some html that reproduces it:

```html
    <html lang="en"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
    <title>Test Test 123</title>                        
                        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="width: 100%; padding-top: 1px;">
                <div class="contents"
                     style="width: 512px; flex-shrink: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;">
                    <div class="contents-body"
                         style="display: block; width: 512px;">
                        <table style="width:50%; border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr style="justify-content:center;align-items:center;gap:56px;color:#848585">
                                    <th style="padding-top:8px;padding-bottom: 10px; font-style:normal;font-weight:500;line-height:16px;letter-spacing:0.1px;text-align:left;width:25%">Column A</th>
                                    <th style="padding-top:8px;padding-bottom: 10px; font-style:normal;font-weight:500;line-height:16px;letter-spacing:0.1px;text-align:left;width:25%">Column B</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td rowspan="3"
                                        style="width:25%; padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px; text-align:left;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;font-weight:500;line-height:16px; letter-spacing:0.1px;">Entry A</td>
                                    <td style="padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px; text-align:left;font-size:14px;font-style: normal;font-weight:400;line-height: 16px;letter-spacing:0.1px;text-decoration-line:underline;">
                                        <a style="color:#E25323; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 50 px;"
                                           href="https://localhost">ABC123ABC-ABC123ABC`</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

It doesn't seem to like the 50px width on the anchor tag text, I think the column width is messing it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it not to wrap, add `white-space:nowrap`;
If you want to set `width` set it `50px`, not `50 px` (spaces not allowed);
If you want `width` to take effect, make your `<a>` block-level, e.g. with `display:inline-block`

And here you are:

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Test Test 123</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; padding-top: 1px;">
    <div class="contents" style="width: 512px; flex-shrink: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;">
      <div class="contents-body" style="display: block; width: 512px;">
        <table style="width:50%; border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="justify-content:center;align-items:center;gap:56px;color:#848585">
              <th style="padding-top:8px;padding-bottom: 10px; font-style:normal;font-weight:500;line-height:16px;letter-spacing:0.1px;text-align:left;width:25%">Column A</th>
              <th style="padding-top:8px;padding-bottom: 10px; font-style:normal;font-weight:500;line-height:16px;letter-spacing:0.1px;text-align:left;width:25%">Column B</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="3" style="width:25%; padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px; text-align:left;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;font-weight:500;line-height:16px; letter-spacing:0.1px;">Entry A</td>
              <td style="padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px; text-align:left;font-size:14px;font-style: normal;font-weight:400;line-height: 16px;letter-spacing:0.1px;text-decoration-line:underline;">
                <a style="color:#E25323; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; display:inline-block; width: 50px; white-space:nowrap" href="https://localhost">ABC123ABC-ABC123ABC`</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the no-wrap was essential to get it to stop wrapping at a hyphen.  Otherwise it would wrap at the hyphen and I would the text wrapped and both halves of the anchor text wrapped and truncated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use block level element:

```
 <a style="color:#E25323; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 50 px;"
                                       href="https://localhost">ABC123ABC-ABC123ABC`</a>
```

In your above code you need to correct 50px remove space "50 px" after that you need to apply display block, so it should be

```
<a style="color:#E25323; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 50px; display: block"
                                       href="https://localhost">ABC123ABC-ABC123ABC`</a>
```